# How to draw line above text in Java

Tags: java, graphics, coordinates, line

I would like to draw a line above a text in Java. I use Graphics and here is my code :

```java
String s = a.getSequent().toString();
FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
int textHeight = fm.getHeight();
int textWidth= fm.stringWidth(s);

//Text
g.drawString( s,
        (int) ((jPanelWidth- textWidth) / 2),
        (int) ((jPanelHeight- textHeight ) / 2));

//Draw line
int x1 = (jPanelWidth- textWidth) / 2;
int x2 = x1 + textWidth; //Problem
int y1 = (jPanelHeight- textHeight *4) / 2;
int y2 = y1;
g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Here is what I have :

[image]

I don't understand why the line don't have the same length as my text. The problem is on the value of x2, but why ? Could you help me ?

Comment: Maybe you get the width for the wrong font. Maybe try to get the FontMetrics for g.getFont()  instead of just getFont() - maybe they are different.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @luk2302 said, here is the solution :

I had : `FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());`

Now I have : `FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());`

I didn't use the right font.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more obscure concepts to come to grips with is understanding how text is actually rendered.

Rather than been rendered from x/y position down, text is rendered from the baseline up.

[image: Text baseline]

This means that the x/y position actually represents the baseline ... just take some time to read that again and if that doesn't help, have a read of [Measuring Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)

The basic concept is, you want take the x/y position, which represents the baseline and then subtract the ascent

[image: For example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);

            String text = "This is a test";
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            int textHeight = fm.getHeight();
            int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);

            int xPos = (getWidth() - textWidth) / 2;
            int yPos = ((getHeight() - textHeight) / 2) + fm.getAscent();

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawString(text, xPos, yPos);

            g2d.drawLine(xPos, yPos - fm.getAscent(), xPos + textWidth, yPos - fm.getAscent());

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this will help me for the rest of my project !

Comment: I use Graphics, not Graphics2D, there is a difference ?

Comment: Generally speaking, in Java, any system generated `Graphics` context is actually an instance of `Graphics2D`